# QR codes in Android

Tags: android, qr-code

I'm searching a third-party library for scanning QR-codes in Android? Could you tell me  one?

I'm looking for one that doesn't call any other app. I want it integrated with my app.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Comment: You want it free of cost also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)?

Answer (score 4):

Look at [ZXing ("Zebra Crossing")](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) I think it solved your problem.

**ZXing (pronounced "zebra crossing")** is an open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java, with ports to other languages. Our focus is on using the built-in camera on mobile phones to scan and decode barcodes on the device, without communicating with a server. However the project can be used to encode and decode barcodes on desktops and servers as well.

And if you want to use with Intents then [How to scan a barcode from another Android application via Intents](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent).

Thanks.,

Comment: Thanks! My first try was with that... But, do I have to use intents to call another app (as I've seen intutorials) or can I use it directly from my app?

Comment: You can use this library in your application code, or if you want to use it with intent then install it .apk on your device then using intent you can call it.

Comment: And licence is Apache License 2.0.

Comment: You can create a jar file using ant and include it with your application. In that case the intent it calls will be internal to the app and you wont need to depend on an external application.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to use it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Zbar? It is easyer to integrate with then XZing, if you really cant use there intents.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/